# Creating Grade Ranges using Arrays

Tags: c++

I am having trouble trying to creating a function that for each letter grade will:

1. Get from the user the grade string and range of possible scores for that grade.
2. Open the file containing the scores.
3. Determine the number of scores in the file in the specified range.
4. Close the file.

How can I achieve this in C++?

Comment: Please provide your current solution and describe specific issues you are facing with it.

Comment: I'd suggest that you turn your requirements into a bullet list and tackle them one by one. You will likely find a SO answer for each requirement. How to get user input, how to open a file, how to read a file into a list/vector, how to get the length of a list, how to filter a list of numbers within a specified range and so on.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of what you've tried so far and the exact problem you're having with it

Answer (score -2):

```
int ranges(String grade)
{
if(grade == 'A')
  cout << "The score should be in between 80 to 100";
else if(grade == 'B') 
  cout << "The score should be in between 60 to 80";
else if (grade == 'C')
  cout << "The score should be in between 50 to 60 ";
else if (grade == 'D')
  cout << "The score should be in between 40 to 50"
}
```

I'm not sure about grade ranges so please edit according to your requirement.

Comment: There are a number of simple errors in the posted code and the answer does not correctly address the question. That said, this is currently not a good question to answer as the asker has posted a very weak question.

Comment: I agree that's why I asked him to clarify the question with some sample input and kind of output